# Multi-split Daikin air-conditioner errors and temperature issues

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling, temperature, mini-split

I have two indoor Daikin Perfera FTXM-R units hooked to a 2MXM-N9 outdoor unit. What I noticed is that the indoor unit closer to the outdoor unit (A) will start to report a very low temperature if I run only the farther away unit (B) on cooling. For example, unit A started reporting an aberrant 15 degrees Celsius when unit B was set to 23 degrees.

On top of this if running both units or just B for a few hours, I get A5 error (freeze-up protection trigger) on the A unit and UH error on the B unit (meaning another unit has failed: unit A).

I also report hearing snapping sounds in the A unit and also an air current even when its turned off, while only B is running.

What could be the root cause of such an issue? Wiring, sensors, piping?

Update: Reversing A and B has the same undesirable behavior and produced error but in a mirrored way. The conclusion is that the AC entering freeze protection is the one not active. I can assume why this happens is related to the cold refrigerant duct in proximity to the units' room temperature sensors, especially when an unit does not make use of it (being not turned on), but I refuse to believe the product design did not anticipate this, as it is a regular multi-split system with two indoor units.
Running both units at the same time only increases the time until one enters freeze protection mode after entering standby while the other is still active.